# Creating new notes in Apple Notes with a PDF attachment

Tags: pdf, applescript

I am planning to use an Hazel to watch a folder. 
When a pdf or any file is dropped into the folder, i want to create a note in Apple Notes (on El Capitan) with the file as an attachment.

Here's my limited progress so far, created as an embedded script in a Hazel rule:

```
tell application "Notes"
   make new note at folder "Notes" 
end tell
```

This creates a blank note ok.

From research, i can see i need to create an HTML img tag in the body of the note text pointing to the attachment in the folder, but i am beyond my knowledge on how to achieve this... any help welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
tell application "Notes"
    set mynote to make new note at folder "Notes"
    make new attachment at mynote with data "mypdf.pdf"
end tell
```